# Microsoft symbols don't get downloaded - 404 error

Tags: windows, symbols, windbg

The Microsoft symbol servers are online but somehow I am not able to download *any* symbols.

I tried to narrow it down to following POC. It should just download the symbols of aadtb.dll but it returns a **HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND**.

```
symchk /v /r c:\windows\system32\aadtb.dll /s SRV*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Alternatively, I tried downloading the pdb using following different Powershell methods but this also returned **404** messages

```
$url = "https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/aadtb.pdb/BC45F7DA843249FFA96D9396BEE5F35D1/aadtb.pdb"
$output = "c:\test.pdb"

(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output
```

I still suspect an issue on my end but do note that I did try on two different machines and through 3 different VPN tunnels, all with the same result. *It worked last Friday, 25/10 on a completely different machine at work.*

Before going completely insane, can someone verify if they can still download symbols, preferably the symbols I mentioned?

### Edit

kernel32.dll and ntdll give the same result <sub>snipped for brevity</sub>

```
symchk /v c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll /s SRV*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
symchk /v c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll /s SRV*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/kernel32.pdb/5A77DE8CE8D58731F0EA38F1C92F48D81/kernel32.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND

SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/0C2E19EA1901E9B82E4567D2D21E56D21/ntdll.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
```

### Edit 2

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418]
```

---

### Output of symchk

```
SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

[SYMCHK] Searching for symbols to c:\windows\system32\aadtb.dll in path SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
[SYMCHK] Using search path "SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols"
DBGHELP: No header for c:\windows\system32\aadtb.dll.  Searching for image on disk
DBGHELP: c:\windows\system32\aadtb.dll - OK
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1
         c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         aadtb.pdb
         BC45F7DA843249FFA96D9396BEE5F35D1
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\symbols\aadtb.pdb\BC45F7DA843249FFA96D9396BEE5F35D1\aadtb.pdb - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\symbols\aadtb.pdb\BC45F7DA843249FFA96D9396BEE5F35D1\aadtb.pd_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\symbols\aadtb.pdb\BC45F7DA843249FFA96D9396BEE5F35D1\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/index2.txt
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190190 - HTTP_STATUS_BAD_REQUEST
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/aadtb.pdb/BC45F7DA843249FFA96D9396BEE5F35D1/aadtb.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/aadtb.pdb/BC45F7DA843249FFA96D9396BEE5F35D1/aadtb.pd_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/aadtb.pdb/BC45F7DA843249FFA96D9396BEE5F35D1/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: aadtb - no symbols loaded
[SYMCHK] MODULE64 Info ----------------------
[SYMCHK] Struct size: 1680 bytes
[SYMCHK] Base: 0x0000000180000000
[SYMCHK] Image size: 1986560 bytes
[SYMCHK] Date: 0x5c901636
[SYMCHK] Checksum: 0x001eadb3
[SYMCHK] NumSyms: 0
[SYMCHK] SymType: SymNone
[SYMCHK] ModName: aadtb
[SYMCHK] ImageName: c:\windows\system32\aadtb.dll
[SYMCHK] LoadedImage: c:\windows\system32\aadtb.dll
[SYMCHK] PDB: ""
[SYMCHK] CV: RSDS
[SYMCHK] CV DWORD: 0x53445352
[SYMCHK] CV Data:  aadtb.pdb
[SYMCHK] PDB Sig:  0
[SYMCHK] PDB7 Sig: {BC45F7DA-8432-49FF-A96D-9396BEE5F35D}
[SYMCHK] Age: 1
[SYMCHK] PDB Matched:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] DBG Matched:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] Line nubmers: FALSE
[SYMCHK] Global syms:  FALSE
[SYMCHK] Type Info:    FALSE
[SYMCHK] ------------------------------------
SymbolCheckVersion  0x00000002
Result              0x00010001
DbgFilename         aadtb.dbg
DbgTimeDateStamp    0x00000000
DbgSizeOfImage      0x00000000
DbgChecksum         0x00000000
PdbFilename         aadtb.pdb
PdbSignature        {BC45F7DA-8432-49FF-A96D-9396BEE5F35D}
PdbDbiAge           0x00000001
[SYMCHK] [ 0x00000000 - 0x00010001 ] Checked "c:\windows\system32\aadtb.dll"
SYMCHK: aadtb.dll            FAILED  - aadtb.pdb mismatched or not found

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 1
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 0
```

### Output of Powershell download methods

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
At line:4 char:1
+ (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At line:5 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Start-BitsTransfer : HTTP status 404: The requested URL does not exist on the server.
At line:6 char:1
+ Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBitsTransferCommand
```

Comment: Do you get the same results using kernel32 and others as well? Sometimes when Windows updates the newest debug symbols aren't immediately available.

Comment: @PickleRick - Kernel32 and ntdll give the same result. I'll update the question

Comment: Well you can see from the log that it's correctly reading the file from disk to generate the request URL. You can then see the HTTP request returns the correct error, there are no symbols for it. If you're getting that error for everything it's possible that it's incorrectly reading something but it looks fine from the log. Could you share the results for both ntdll.dll and ntoskrnl.exe?

Comment: Do you happen to know how the request URL gets generated?

Comment: Never looked into it but it would appear to me that it reads in the IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY from the PE header and uses data there to generate the URL.

Comment: @PickleRick - tx, you were right. [dumpbin /headers](https://community.osr.com/discussion/219184/getting-pdb7-sig-from-binary) shows the GUID used in the generated URL. I have updated the question to include the results for ntdll.dll and kernel32.dll.

Comment: look like or problem on server or something changed. i also can not download symbols today

Comment: @RbMm - thanks for checking. I learned a lot today but not what I was set out to do ;)

Comment: [*Please mail suggestions or bug reports to windbgfb@microsoft.com.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols#symbol-resources-and-feedback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like some kinda SNAFU on Microsoft part. So, yeah, like @[RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) pointed out, send an email to WinDbgFb@microsoft.com to let them know. And maybe also tweet it to [Andy Luhrs](https://twitter.com/aluhrs13). Keep in mind though that it's a small team, and they might not be able to do anything until Monday (here in US.)

Answer (score 1):

The file simply does not exist on the server.

Can [this](https://lise.pnfsoftware.com/winpdb/CAC308E4DB4A46CC07EDA8F09F7DFEB50619DE9FD42AF6F9132B7FA64956516C-aadtb.html) help you?

Comment: No, sorry I should have made it more clear but I can't download *any* pdb file.

Comment: Hmm. That's weird. Perhaps maybe they screwed something up on their end?
Could send another pdb link from theirs so I can confirm It's not functional.

Comment: How about this one? `$url = "https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/0C2E19EA1901E9B82E4567D2D21E56D21/ntdll.pdb"`

Comment: Are you able to download any symbols? Do you have an URL I can try to download?

Comment: That file also does not download. This is a problem with Microsoft and has nothing to do with your network to be specific.

Comment: Have you tried WinSDK? I remember symbols do come with it?

Comment: I'm trying to analyze a dump from another computer and it lead me to this issue with symbols, also on my own device. I have no WinSDK for the version of Windows I'm trying to analyze the dump from. Thanks for trying the links Nurudin.

Comment: sdk or wdk not containing symbols. and must be ability download symbols from server by guid+age in debug directory. but today something was broken